# Proposal: Synonymize [syntax] and [sentence-construction]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, tag-cleaning

It seems we can achieve a consensus on a certain set of tags this time without reading too much into things. Let's clean up sentence-related tags. I just came up with a few ideas, and I present them in separate meta posts so we could discuss each of them.

**Proposal one:** Let's synonymize [sentence-construction](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sentence-construction) to point to [syntax](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/syntax) ([Wikipedia entry for syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax)).

[syntax](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/syntax) is more general, more correct, and can replace [grammar](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar) more effectively where it should. After the synonymizing, people would still be able to tag their question as "sentence-construction", it's just that the tag name would show as *syntax*, so there isn't a "learner can't choose" argument here.

What do you think?

Comment: I can't vote on a synonym I created, lol. I forgot I had done that.

Comment: @Colleen wait, I meant the other way around. I wanted "syntax" to be the master . . .

Comment: I meant syntax to be the master also. Did I mess up which was which? Yeah I think I did, but I can't suggest the synonym on syntax because I don't have the score for it

Comment: @ColleenV: We'd need fully 1/4 of the users with 5+ score in that tag to get the synonym approved that way, I think.

Answer (score 5):

**So, we can't propose [sentence-construction](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sentence-construction) as a synonym of [syntax](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/syntax) because it is much more commonly used. We'll have to figure out a different way to go about it if this is important to folks. In the meantime, I'm going to take this off the list because we can't complete it as proposed.**

I think we have enough support to create this synonym, but it's been a while since we talked about it, so I'm going to feature this discussion for a week or so.

If you don't feel that we should make [sentence-construction](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sentence-construction) a synonym of [syntax](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/syntax) so that when people enter [sentence-construction](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sentence-construction), [syntax](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/syntax) is what appears on the question please leave a comment or answer explaining why.